# Pycharm debugger doesn't work properly with system commands

Tags: python, pycharm, ocrmypdf

I'm trying to debug a program with the following command

`os.system('ocrmypdf -l por --force-ocr --pages 1 \"' + dirname + '/' + pdf_name + '\" \"' + ocr_dir + str(index) + '.pdf\"')`

When I run the code it works, but in the debugger it displays the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocrmypdf.__main__'; 'ocrmypdf' is not a package`

And the command doesn't work. As the program **runs normally when not on the debug mode** I think it is some Pycharm configuration, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: If you are using pycharm and also calling `os.system`, I'd recommend rethinking your approach. Using pycharm suggests you are developing more than a simple script. `os.system` really doesn't belong anywhere besides quick and dirty utility scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried replacing ```os.system``` by ```subprocess.run```, but it error is the same. Do you have any other suggestion?